# Archive Meta on Product Post Type

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, custom-post-type-archives, wp-get-archives

I am using a filtered search to provide end user the ability to browse either live/published Woocommerce product listings or archived product listings; however, I am running into an issue where I am unable to expose a metakey for 'is_archived_()'. This is resulting in the user search pulling a mix of published and archived and is confusing from an ecomm standpoint.

How I would like to approach this is:  on the product post template, IF product post IS archived, apply new tag value = Expired.
Admittedly, I am not well versed yet in get_query functions, so any help on how the code would look is immensely appreciated.

Cheers all,

Abe

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by expose a meta key for `is_archived_()`? WP has no function by that name

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for weighing in.  I think I can be more clear as I am simplifying my use case and learning as I go.  All I am really looking to do is create a new taxonomy under which the tags are conditionally populated based on post status.  ie.  if the post is archived, auto apply tag 'Expired'

Comment: Can you ellaborate what you mean by an archived post? The post statuses that come with WordPress are `draft` `auto` `new` `pending` `future` and `publish`

Comment: Yes, I'm using WooCommerce and time dependent product listings based on an auction plugin.  I see what you mean on default post statuses; I believe the archive status I'm currently referencing is originating from that software or WooCommerce Frontend Marketplace plugin.  Archived is an available option within the post status dropdown.  

I've since created a custom post taxonomy with corresponding tags, now it's just a matter of conditionally applying it.